# How to resize images client side using jquery file upload

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery-file-upload, blueimp, jquery-fileupload-rails

I am using [blueimp jquery-file-upload](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload) in a Rails 3.2 app, via the [jquery-fileupload-rails](https://github.com/tors/jquery-fileupload-rails) gem.

I am trying to resize images on the client side prior to uploading, but am having trouble following the documentation. My code is below. Currently uploading works perfectly, but the images are not resized.

What is the correct syntax to resize images via jquery-file-upload.

(Two approaches shown in the coffeescript based on [this](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Client-side-Image-Resizing) and [this](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Upload-multiple-resolutions-of-one-image-with-multiple-resize-options) documentation. Neither works for me.)

```
#Coffeescript

jQuery ->
  if $("#new_asset").length
    $("#new_asset").fileupload 
      dataType: "script"
      add: (e, data) ->
        types = /(\.|\/)(jpe?g|png)$/i
        file = data.files[0]
        if types.test(file.type) || types.test(file.name)
          data.context = $(tmpl("template-upload", file))
          $('#progress-container').append(data.context)
          jqXHR = data.submit()
          $("button.cancel").click (e) ->
            jqXHR.abort()
        else
          alert("#{file.name} is not a jpeg or png image file")
      progress: (e, data) ->
        if data.context
          progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10)
          data.context.find('.bar').css('width', progress + '%')
      stop: (e, data) ->
        $('.upload').hide()
      process: [
        action: "load"
        fileTypes: /^image\/(gif|jp?g)$/
        maxFileSize: 20000000 # 20MB
      ,
        action: "resize"
        imageMaxWidth: 1500
        imageMaxHeight: 1500
      ,
        action: "save"
      ]
      dropZone: $(".dropzone")
      sequentialUploads: true
      disableImageResize: /Android(?!.*Chrome)|Opera/.test(window.navigator and navigator.userAgent)
      imageMaxWidth: 1500
      imageMaxHeight: 1500
      downloadTemplateId: null

#application.js
//= require jquery-fileupload
```

**EDIT**

According to Matanza's answer, the `add` callback in my code prevents any processing functions from being called automatically. So I assume I need to do something like

```
...
add: (e, data) -> 
  $.each data.result, (index, file) ->
    // processing code goes here
```

But I'm having a lot of trouble working out the correct syntax or making sense of the guides that are available.

How do I apply the resize processing to each file in the add callback?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I solved it by calling the process within the add callback like so:

```
add: (e, data) ->
  current_data = $(this)
  data.process(->
    return current_data.fileupload('process', data);
  ).done(->
    data.submit(); 
  )
```

also remember to load your JS files in the right order in application.js....(this wasted several hours of my life):

```
//= require jquery-fileupload/vendor/jquery.ui.widget
//= require jquery-fileupload/vendor/load-image
//= require jquery-fileupload/vendor/canvas-to-blob
//= require jquery-fileupload/jquery.iframe-transport
//= require jquery-fileupload/jquery.fileupload
//= require jquery-fileupload/jquery.fileupload-ui
//= require jquery-fileupload/jquery.fileupload-process
//= require jquery-fileupload/jquery.fileupload-validate
//= require jquery-fileupload/jquery.fileupload-image
```

Comment: thanks @dannio. This looks very promising. Looking at the code in your SO question has also been very helpful. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22753646/using-jquery-fileupload-with-coffeescript-resizing-image-when-using-add-callba. But, I am getting a console error when I upload a file. "Uncaught type error. Undefined is not a function" related to this line: `return current_data.fileupload('process', data);`. Any idea what the problem could be?

Comment: OK, seems that I had an outdated version of one of the js files in my app which was conflicting with the recent version. Got rid of this and the type error disappeared. And after examining files that have been uploaded, they are now all resizing as expected! So very very very happy to have finally fixed this issue. Thank you thank you!!!

Comment: While I have a different implementation of the **add** function, the main setback in my case was the order of the JS files. I can't thank you enough for this post!
And here's my **add** implementation if you are interested:
`$(this).fileupload('process', data).done(function () {
 data.submit();
});
`

Answer (score 1):

If that is still relevant- 
I found out that once you use the add callback, it is your responsibility to add whatever processing stages that you require. So for that matter if you remove the add callback it will resize the image with your settings.
what you should do is register the resize processing settings to each file in the add function

hope that helps

Comment: Thanks for the help!  Do you have an example of how to register the resize processing settings?

Comment: Hi @matanza, I'm still having trouble working out the syntax to process files within the add callback. Could you provide a code example? I assume I need something like `add: (e, data) -> $.each data.result, (index, file) -> // process code goes here`. But what does the process code look like?

Answer (score 1):

I had trouble getting Image resize to work. In the end I started again. I had added image resize to an existing working file upload code. For me, it was the custom add that was hindering the resize. Once I removed the custom add, it was hunky-dorey. Just wanted to put it out there for the benefit of other strugglers.